# class Meta Django

Tags: python, django

Good evening,

In fact I would have liked to have explanations in relation to the Meta class. In my case, if I don't code it, it doesn't change anything. I imagine it's because in the settings I filled in the user model used for the project. But beyond filling in the class linked to the form, I have trouble understanding the fields attribute. Because I can interchange, remove items from the list, it doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance

```
class UserPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Shopper
        fields = ["old_password", "new_password", "new_password2"]
```

Apart from the model, what is the class meta for?

Comment: The `Meta` class in your form doesn't really matter because: 1. `PasswordChangeForm` is a `Form` and not a `ModelForm` so the `model` you specify doesn't do anything. 2. Your `fields` are the same as the fields declared on the form so again don't change anything.